# How to save a Akka Stream of Case class to Kafka directly?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream

I am able to save my data to Kafka in form of String like this :

```
 val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(actorSystem, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")


def kafkaSink(source: Source[ModbusMessage, NotUsed]) = source.map(a => s"Id:${a.sensorId}:Values:${a.values.mkString(",")}").map { m =>
    new ProducerRecord[String, String]("sampleData", m)
  }.
    runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
```

, but is there a way to save my case class directly into Kafka. Like if I want to save my data in form of My case class ModbusMessage.

If someone can provide me a quick example that would be great !

Thanks.
Help is appreciated !

Comment: Are you talking about serialization? If so, do you want a textual representation (such as JSON), or a binary representation?

Comment: Whichever is best for performance ! Do I need to convert it into Json using library like liftJson and then save it as a String inside Kafka ?

Comment: That is generally broad. I would go with a simplified JSON approach first.

Comment: If you can provide me an example to do this ,using Binary as well as Json which ever is best for performance would be great !

Comment: There are many JSON libraries for Scala, such as Play Json, Circe, Json4s and so on. Google them and you will get examples. This is a simple approach however in general performance and latency will be better with binary. In that case you could use something like Protobuf or Avro. Again, google is your friend. These will be more performant, but there's a bit more to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka's model of a data message, which consists of a message key and a message value, is based on raw bytes (`byte[]`) for keys and values.  So you need to provide a serializer that converts your case class into `byte[]`.  In your example above, you have configured the use of `StringSerializer` for both keys and values, and the serializer converts `String -> byte[]`.

> but is there a way to save my case class directly into Kafka. Like if I want to save my data in form of My case class ModbusMessage.

If you have a case class `ModbusMessage`, then you need to implement + configure a `ModbusMessage -> byte[]` serializer.  You can implement such a serializer yourself, but as others have commented on your question you can also opt for serialization frameworks such as Avro or Protobuf.  You may also want to look at e.g. https://github.com/scala/pickling.

> Do I need to convert it into Json using library like liftJson and then save it as a String inside Kafka ?

No, you don't need to. You can -- and most probably also should -- convert directly from your case class `ModbusMessage` to `byte[]` (and, for deserialization, in the opposite direction).  There's no point in converting your case class first to JSON, because the JSON representation, too, must be serialized to `byte[]` so that it can be sent to Kafka (so you'd incur twice the conversion cost here).